# How to correctly convert GLSL *- operator to HLSL?

Tags: glsl, hlsl

I'm trying to port GLSL code to HLSL but I'm getting type mismatch error at the end of this operation:

```
float2 pos = p;
float a = time * 100. + y * 31.;
float2 lineCenter = vec2(0.5, y);   
pos -= lineCenter;
pos *- float2x2(cos(a), -sin(a), sin(a), cos(a));
```

The *- operator confuses me a lot, how can it be converted properly to HLSL?

Comment: There is no "`*-`" operator in glsl. Where did you find that code? I assume it is meant to be "`*=`". Can you please show the original glsl code?

Comment: @Rabbid76 This is the code I'm trying http://glslsandbox.com/e#55828.0
I also assumed it was *= but if I change it to:

 `pos = mul(pos, float2x2(cos(a), -sin(a), sin(a), cos(a))); `

the whole shader works but the image is distorted.

Answer (score 1):

The line does nothing and can be removed.

Basically `*-` does a computation as it multiplies the left part `pos` with the negative right part `float2x2(cos(a), -sin(a), sin(a), cos(a))`, but as this line has no assignment the result of that operation just gets discarded and never used.

You can test it in your [reference](http://glslsandbox.com/e#55828.0) as you can remove the lines 23-28 without changing anything in the resulting picture.

Comment: wow what a bamboozle...
put this in your code if you want to make it impossible to understand for beginners i guess